# How to handle group level variable in oracle PL/SQL, so that i can access individual as well as group level variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, cobol

Currently we are working on migration of COBOL code into oracle PL/SQL. In COBOL there is a record/group level variable concept, eg.

```
    01 PARENT-VAR.
       05 CHILD-1 PIC 9(2) VALUE 12.
       05 CHILD-2 PIC 9(3) VALUE 345.
```

Basically it means, we can access individual variable `CHILD-`1 or `CHILD-2`. Also if we access `PARENT-VAR`, we will get the value of both child variables auto-concatenated as: `12345`.

If we try to implement same concept in PL/SQL we can use `IS RECORD` as:

```
 TYPE TYP_PARENT_VAR IS RECORD
 ( CHILD-1 NUMBER(2) := 12,
   CHILD-2 NUMBER(3) := 345);

   VAR TYP_PARENT_VAR;
```

Now I can access individual child variables as `VAR.CHILD-1` or `VAR.CHILD-2`. But if I have to access both variables at once, I see no way to do it without manual concatenation.

How can we access both the parent and the child-items?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'access both variables at once'. In what sense can't you access them?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you are saying that COBOL is concatenating two numbers as if they are text? That is very bizarre. Do you have some example code we could see? This could be implemented with objects, but it will not be done automatically.

Comment: Because COBOL != PLSQL. Those programming rules don't apply and you must forget those old ways of  code behaviour. Tell us what you want to ultimately do rather than asking how to handle variables like that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, as i have mentioned in above example, there is no way i can display(or use) variable VAR. I have to access VAR.CHILD_1 or VAR.CHILD_2. I cant access directly VAR (which should give value of VAR.CHILD_1 and VAR.CHILD_2).

Comment: @BrianLeach, Here is example for same:
             IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
             PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
             DATA DIVISION.
             WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
             01 PARENT-VAR.
                 05 CHILD-1 PIC 9(2) VALUE 12.
                 05 CHILD-2 PIC 9(3) VALUE 345.
             PROCEDURE DIVISION.
             DISPLAY 'PARENT-VAR='PARENT-VAR.
             STOP RUN.

Output for this is:
PARENT-VAR=12345

Comment: @KaushikNayak, I completly understand COBOL != PLSQL.But when you have a million line of code to convert from COBOL to PLSQL, we have to find some way to implement it. Most of the us thought to use record structure to implement this as mentioned in above example.
We want to find some way to get the above requirement (access multiple variables at once by given type variable or anything which is possible).
We are tryingfor this because we need to write script which will convert the code directly from COBOL to PLSQL without manual intervention.
Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks

Comment: @theitguy Simon Sobisch's edit clarified that *'access both variables at once'* meant concatenating the two record elements into one string. I am still not sure what this would achieve in PL/SQL. Perhaps some code illustrating the desired behaviour in use would help.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL uses compressed binary-coded decimal to encode numbers.
Those can't be concatenated like uncompressed BCD used by Cobol.

So you will be compelled to use some code to do the trick (ie `CHILD-1 * 1000 + CHILD-2` or cast them as char and use string concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at computed columns.  (SQL syntax is not really my thing, so this is likely wrong)

```
ALTER TABLE cobol_record
  add column parent_var COMPUTED BY concat(to_char(child_1), to_char(child_2));
```

Or do that during create

```
CREATE TABLE cobol_record
(
  child_1  number(2),
  child_2  number(3),
  parent_var COMPUTED BY CONCAT(TO_CHAR(child_1), TO_CHAR(child_2))
)
```

It won't take space in the table, but will let you do whatever concatenation you need.  Yes, it's a manual concatenation, but only once, during the table definition.  From what little I read, these fields are not computed until needed, so performance shouldn't take much of a hit.

And again, that syntax is off the top of a head that knows very little about Oracle SQL.